# Why I'm receving "IOError: bad message length" in pipe?

Tags: python, pipe, fork

I created this program to multiply two matrices with fork and report the result to the father with pipe.

The program works correctly, but in the end I get the following error message:

```
File "ep2_fork.py", line 105, in <module>
myVar1 = pipe_pai.recv()
IOError: bad message length
```

What could it be?

(Some parts of the code have been removed since they are not need to the question)

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pipe

def multiplicacao1(pipe_filho):
    myVar1 = productMatrix(A[0:len(A)/2], B)
    pipe_filho.send(myVar1)

def multiplicacao2(pipe_filho):
    myVar2 = productMatrix(A[len(A)/2:], B)
    pipe_filho.send(myVar2)

matrixSize = random.randint(1, 25)

A = createMatrix(matrixSize)
B = createMatrix(matrixSize)

print "\nAs matrizes geradas foram:\n"

printMatrix(A)
print
printMatrix(B)

pipe_filho, pipe_pai = Pipe()

pid_filho = os.fork()

if pid_filho == 0:
    multiplicacao1(pipe_filho)
    time.sleep(1)

pid_neto = os.fork()

if pid_neto == 0:
    multiplicacao2(pipe_filho)
    time.sleep(1)               

myVar1 = pipe_pai.recv() # Line 105
myVar2 = pipe_pai.recv()

print "\nO produto das duas matrizes e:\n"
printMatrix(myVar1+myVar2)
```

Comment: Is `pipe_filho, pipe_pai = Pipe()` the correct initialization for `pipe_pai`?

Comment: Yes, it his. The program is working fine. The problem is that in the end I receive always the IOError.